# Uninstall phonegap from windows 7

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-7, window

can anyone tell me the proper way to uninstall phonegap 2.9.1 from windows 7. can't find it in any of my uninstaller program. i don't think just deleting the folder is the proper way. 
Thanks

Comment: Have u made use of CLI while installation ?

Comment: i do, i create folder for the project from cmd to use in eclipse

Comment: From CLI run this command sudo npm uninstall cordova -g

Comment: isn't sudo command used for linux ? tried the command but it gives me error " sudo, is not recognized as an internal or external command. operable program or batch file "

Comment: hmmmm it keeps saying npm WARN uninstall not installed.. i am pretty sure i installed the npm. i tried running the uninstall c folder and also within the phonegap. can't find it !! if i don't have the CLI, whats the good way to uninstall it. Actually, i wanna downgrade to some lower version like 2.9.0 ..

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you installed with node.js, then you simply go

```
npm uninstall phonegap
```

to remove the local package or

```
npm uninstall --global phonegap
```

to remove the global install